# Always display columns in rdlc Matrix

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

Using a Tablix Matrix I am aggregating a count based on the values in a single column.  With results similar the below.

```
Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
4        2      3      3
```

The problem occurs that with certain criteria there might not be a value2 or value3.  When this happen the column does not appear at all.  How do I force it to show all columns even if there is nothing to count?  Thanks

Data source:

```
FieldToCount PersonName
Value1       Mandy
Value3       John
Value3       Jack
Value4       Jack
Value2       Mandy
Value1       John
```

[image: Matrix]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Count` function in the report, try to write this formula in the column cell

```
=IIf(Count(Fields!FieldToCount.Value) > 0, 
     Count(Fields!FieldToCount.Value),
     0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work.  Since this is a matrix (like a cross tab/pivot) Value2 is a value and not a field name.

Comment: Could you write how is the result data (columns and some values)  of your query? because I think I have the same structure, that's why I think it works,

Comment: I added the data source to the question.  So even if the the criteria was PersonName = "Mandy" I would want to to see zero values for all four values.  Thanks

Comment: What do you use to Count? do you use a report function like this Count(Fields!FieldToCount .Value)? I Edited my answer

Comment: Yes, I use Count(Fields!FieldToCount .Value).  Added image to question.

Comment: I edited my answer before, did you try it or it did not work?

Comment: No it does not work.  The column does not appear at all so there is nothing to count.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried setting the

```
RepeatColumnHeaders = True
```

?

It is located in the properties box after you click the whole matrix.